# Create a rolling date in a query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I am trying to create a query that runs against its own results until the results have satisfied what I am looking for. I need to write SQL that will tell me what the next row's `[ProjStart]` date should be based on the previous row's `[ProjStart]` date + the previous rows `[EffortDays]`, per `[EmpName]`. The order of each task is based on the `[Position]` column partitioned by the `[EmpName]`. The trick is that not all rows will have a date until the query tells it to have the `[ProjStart]`+`[EffortDays]` of the previous row.

Below is a sample table to help create the desired results

```
DECLARE @aTestTable TABLE  
     (  
        Position int,  
        EmpName   VARCHAR(10),  
        ProjStart  DATE,
        EffortDays int
     );  
  
 INSERT INTO @aTestTable VALUES 
 ('1', 'Adam', '2023-05-01',2),
 ('2', 'Adam', NULL,3), 
 ('3', 'Adam', NULL,1), 
 ('4', 'Adam', NULL,2), 
 ('5', 'Adam', NULL,4), 
 ('6', 'Adam', NULL,3), 
 ('1', 'Bill', '2023-05-07',4), 
 ('2', 'Bill', NULL,5), 
 ('3', 'Bill', NULL,1), 
 ('4', 'Bill', NULL,3), 
 ('5', 'Bill', NULL,6), 
 ('1', 'Bob', '2023-05-10',4),
 ('2', 'Bob', NULL,2),
 ('3', 'Bob', NULL,5),
 ('4', 'Bob', NULL,1),
 ('5', 'Bob', NULL,1),
 ('6', 'Bob', NULL,2),
 ('7', 'Bob', NULL,3),
 ('1', 'Dave', '2023-04-28',2),
 ('2', 'Dave', NULL,1),
 ('3', 'Dave', NULL,5),
 ('4', 'Dave', NULL,4)

 SELECT * FROM @aTestTable
```

Please let me know if I can provide clarification.

Below is the expected output taking the previous rows `[ProjStart]` and adding the previous rows `[EffortDays]` for the current rows `[ProjStart]` partitioned by `[EmpName]` and ordered by `[Position]`.

```
Position    EmpName ProjStart   EffortDays
1   Adam    2023-05-01  2
2   Adam    2023-05-03  3
3   Adam    2023-05-06  1
4   Adam    2023-05-07  2
5   Adam    2023-05-09  4
6   Adam    2023-05-13  3
1   Bill    2023-05-07  4
2   Bill    2023-05-11  5
3   Bill    2023-05-16  1
4   Bill    2023-05-17  3
5   Bill    2023-05-20  6
1   Bob 2023-05-10  4
2   Bob 2023-05-14  2
3   Bob 2023-05-16  5
4   Bob 2023-05-21  1
5   Bob 2023-05-22  1
6   Bob 2023-05-23  2
7   Bob 2023-05-25  3
1   Dave    2023-04-28  2
2   Dave    2023-04-30  1
3   Dave    2023-05-01  5
4   Dave    2023-05-06  4
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Comment: "trying to create a query" in that case please share what you tried, and explain in what way it does not meet the desired results.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should be able to use a windowed sum of effort days from the last date provided, and add them onto the last date provided. I suggested windowed sum of effortdays and min prostart partitioned by user.

Comment: @SelVazi I have edited the original question with desired results.

Comment: @PeterB I do not know what to try which is why I am asking for help. I have tried CTE and then joining back on that CTE with EmpName and Position+1, but that only gets me as far as the second row's ProjStart populated for each EmpName. I need all of the null rows populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that I think will do what you need.

I used a CTE (Common Table Expression) to first retrieve the rows that have `ProjStart` filled in, and then recursively combine the next rows' data with the ProjStart and EffortDate of the previous set of rows to produce ProjStart for the next rows.

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @aTestTable TABLE
(
    Position   INT,
    EmpName    VARCHAR(10),
    ProjStart  DATE,
    EffortDays INT
);
  
INSERT INTO @aTestTable VALUES
  (1, 'Adam', '2023-05-01', 2),
  (2, 'Adam', NULL, 3),
  (3, 'Adam', NULL, 1),
  (4, 'Adam', NULL, 2),
  (5, 'Adam', NULL, 4),
  (6, 'Adam', NULL, 3),
  (1, 'Bill', '2023-05-07', 4),
  (2, 'Bill', NULL, 5),
  (3, 'Bill', NULL, 1),
  (4, 'Bill', NULL, 3),
  (5, 'Bill', NULL, 6),
  (1, 'Bob', '2023-05-10', 4),
  (2, 'Bob', NULL, 2),
  (3, 'Bob', NULL, 5), 
  (4, 'Bob', NULL, 1),
  (5, 'Bob', NULL, 1),
  (6, 'Bob', NULL, 2),
  (7, 'Bob', NULL, 3),
  (1, 'Dave', '2023-04-28', 2),
  (2, 'Dave', NULL, 1),
  (3, 'Dave', NULL, 5),
  (4, 'Dave', NULL, 4)

;WITH mycte AS (
  SELECT Position, EmpName, ProjStart, EffortDays
  FROM   @aTestTable
  WHERE  ProjStart IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT next.Position, next.EmpName, DATEADD(dd, prev.EffortDays, prev.ProjStart) AS ProjStart, next.EffortDays
  FROM   mycte       prev
  JOIN   @aTestTable next ON next.EmpName  = prev.EmpName
                         AND next.Position = prev.Position + 1
)
SELECT * FROM mycte
ORDER BY EmpName, Position
```

**Results:**

| Position | EmpName | ProjStart | EffortDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 2023-05-01 | 2 |
| 2 | Adam | 2023-05-03 | 3 |
| 3 | Adam | 2023-05-06 | 1 |
| 4 | Adam | 2023-05-07 | 2 |
| 5 | Adam | 2023-05-09 | 4 |
| 6 | Adam | 2023-05-13 | 3 |
| 1 | Bill | 2023-05-07 | 4 |
| 2 | Bill | 2023-05-11 | 5 |
| 3 | Bill | 2023-05-16 | 1 |
| 4 | Bill | 2023-05-17 | 3 |
| 5 | Bill | 2023-05-20 | 6 |
| 1 | Bob | 2023-05-10 | 4 |
| 2 | Bob | 2023-05-14 | 2 |
| 3 | Bob | 2023-05-16 | 5 |
| 4 | Bob | 2023-05-21 | 1 |
| 5 | Bob | 2023-05-22 | 1 |
| 6 | Bob | 2023-05-23 | 2 |
| 7 | Bob | 2023-05-25 | 3 |
| 1 | Dave | 2023-04-28 | 2 |
| 2 | Dave | 2023-04-30 | 1 |
| 3 | Dave | 2023-05-01 | 5 |
| 4 | Dave | 2023-05-06 | 4 |

**Working demo fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c3e5c/1/0

PS I do believe that your employees deserve the weekends off, but we'll keep that for another question ;-)

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this?! I swear I tried something very similar and it only gave me the results on the row after the date was populated, and the rest were null. But this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it using window functions `lag()`, `max()` and `sum()`

The function `max()` was used to get the initial ProjStart per Name.

`lag()` was used to get the next EffortDays.

`sum()` will generate a running total based on the next effortDays column, which will be utilized to generate ProjStart for the next rows.

```
with cte as (
       select *,
       max(ProjStart) over (partition by EmpName order by position) as init_ProjStart,
       lag(EffortDays) over (partition by EmpName order by position) as next_EffortDays
       from @aTestTable
),
cte2 as (
  select *, sum(next_EffortDays) over (partition by EmpName order by position ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as running_sum
  from cte
)
select position, EmpName, coalesce(ProjStart, DATEADD(dd, running_sum, init_ProjStart)), EffortDays
from cte2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/eVoP7b4D)